# Android: RecyclerView Show images 2 times

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, picasso

my app get images from firebase-Realtime, and i am using  recyclerview to display them, yet it shows images 2 times, means that if i have 5 images on firebase it would show same 5 images but duplicate them which is 10 images.

my app get images from firebase-Realtime,

my adapter:

```
 @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.private_code_recycler_layout, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
 
        Picasso.get()
                .load(mImages.get(position))
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_baseline_cloud_download_24)
                .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE,MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
                .resize(480,480)
                .into(holder.image);


        holder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, FullScreenImageViewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("ImageURL", mImages.get(position));
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

Activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityWorkDetailsBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        workUid_details = getIntent().getExtras().getString("UID_Details");
        String title = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
        String description = getIntent().getExtras().getString("description");
        String location = getIntent().getExtras().getString("location");
        String path = getIntent().getExtras().getString("path");

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Work").child(path);
        valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                binding.workDetailsTitle.setText(title);
                binding.workDetailsDescription.setText(description);
                binding.workDetailsLocation.setText(location);
                binding.getUIDDetails.setText(workUid_details);

                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.child("images").getChildren()) {
                    String value = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue());
                    imagesFromURL.add(value);
                }
                initRecyclerView();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) { }
        };

    }

    private void initRecyclerView(){
        binding.workDetailsImage.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        binding.workDetailsImage.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        binding.workDetailsImage.setHasFixedSize(true);
        WorkDetailsAdapter adapter = new WorkDetailsAdapter(this, imagesFromURL);
        binding.workDetailsImage.setAdapter(adapter);
        binding.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Comment: I think you should also add the 'java` tag now? The recommended language is now Kotlin so many people use that as well. Just to avoid the confusion (It is not mandatory to migrate to Kotlin, Java is just fine. Kotlin is just easier to write)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `imagesFromURL.clear();` before you add imageUrl.

```
imagesFromURL.clear();//add this line
for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.child("images").getChildren()) {
    String value = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue());
    imagesFromURL.add(value);
}
```

Comment: it worked, thanks, can you explain to me what was the reason?

Comment: @Mini The data you get from firebase is all, so you need to init or clear the list everytime.